# How to round an UIImageView with Autoresizing Masks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

Hello everyone.
               I am creating an iOS app. In which I have got an ImageView on UITableView cell. The problem is whenever I am making it circular by dividing its height or width by 2 its creating an oval. Although when I am removing the autoresizing its working fine. Can anybody please help here.

Comment: height and width of your imageView should be equal, like 50x50.

Comment: Yeah Sushil its 72x72.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found with UITableViewCell that you get strange affects related to size classes when you show rounded images in cells. This is especially the case if you use different size constraints for images on iPad say versus iPhone. To fix this I add the following to my cell class. `self.myImageView` is my cells UIImageView that I want to be round.

This also makes sure you pick up the latest changes in the image frame if it changes during layout.

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    //
    // Make the image round using the latest frame size.
    //
    CALayer *l=[self.myImageView layer];
    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [l setCornerRadius:self.myImageView.frame.size.width/2];

    // No border just now
    [l setBorderWidth:0.0];
    [l setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
}
```

Code assumes the image is square which it needs to be to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Rory, I have implemented your code and its working fine for iPhone 4, 5 but when I am checking it on iPhone 6 plus its width and height changing and margin is little big. 'width = 95' and 'height = 81', Then how it is possible to make it round.

Comment: Worked fine dude, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes than you should give your UIImageview width and height equal to height of your **UITableviewcell** and than divide it by two...

Answer (score 0):

Add this generic method:

```
func addRoundedCorner(viewToRound:UImageView, radius:CGFloat) {

    var layer:CALayer = viewToRound.layer;
    layer.cornerRadius=radius
    layer.masksToBounds = true
} //F.E.
```

Pass your imageview like this:

```
self.addRoundedCorner(YourUImageView, radius:CGFloat(YourUImageView.frame.size.width/2.0))
```

**Note:** Apply it with proper auto resizing else it will not work fine
Thanks